# Initial Value Problem with wrong solution, I can't find my mistake

Tags: calculus, initial-value-problems

Currently I'm working on the following exercise:

$$
4y''+ 4y'+ 5y = 0\,,\qquad y\left(\pi\right) = 1
\,,\quad y'\left(\pi\right) = 0
$$

My solution to this exercise is
$$
{\rm e}^{-x/2}\left[\,{-\cos\left(x\right)/{\rm e}^{-\pi/2} - \sin\left(x\right)/{\rm e}^{-\pi/2}}\,\,\right],
$$
but I'm not sure about this answer since Symbolab ([https://www.symbolab.com/solver/simplify-calculator/4y''%2B4y'%2B5y%3D0%2C%20y%5Cleft(%5Cpi%5Cright)%3D1%2C%20y'%5Cleft(%5Cpi%20%5Cright)%3D0](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/simplify-calculator/4y%27%27%2B4y%27%2B5y%3D0%2C%20y%5Cleft(%5Cpi%5Cright)%3D1%2C%20y%27%5Cleft(%5Cpi%20%5Cright)%3D0)) tells me something else.

Can someone either correct my answer or confirm the correct answer?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4y%27%27%2B+4y%27%2B+5y+%3D+0+%2C+y%28pi%29+%3D+1+%2C+y%27%28pi%29+%3D+0

Comment: @Moo But how do you calculate the constants c1 and c2 correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question easier to read.

Comment: @MartPostma: It is no different than any other IC. You have $y(x)$ as a function of two ICs. Write $y(\pi)$ and $y'(\pi)$ and use those two equations to find the two constants.

Comment: @Moo: Hmm, I'm not sure if I did that part correctly. My c1 and c2 differs from the right solution. Don't know where the problem lies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution is given by

$$y(x) = c_1 e^{-x/2} \sin(x) + c_2 e^{-x/2} \cos(x)$$

The derivative is given by

$$y'(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-x/2} (c_1 (2 \cos(x) - \sin(x)) - c_2 (2 \sin(x) + \cos(x)))$$

Evaluating $y(x)$ at $x = \pi$

$$y(\pi) = -c_2 e^{-\pi/2} = 1$$

Evaluating $y'(x)$ at $x = \pi$

$$y'(\pi) = \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-\pi/2} (c_2 - 2 c_1) = 0$$

Can you solve those two for $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: Ah yes finally! I spot my mistake. Thanks!